# Using only its API, how can I post test results to Team Foundation Server 2010?

Tags: api

I have a process for running automated functional tests which is external to Microsoft Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2010. Test cases are tracked as Test Case work items within TFS, however. After running these tests, how can I publish the results to TFS using the TFS API? Can someone point me to sample code that demonstrates this?

Please note that I expressly want to avoid a solution that requires transformation of my test results into the .trx file format. Searches have turned up dead links, or solutions that rely on this method.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the following blogs may almost be what you're after

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2010/02/23/creating-fake-builds-in-tfs-build-2010.aspx
http://msmvps.com/blogs/vstsblog/archive/2011/04/26/creating-fake-builds-in-tfs-build-2010-using-the-command-line.aspx

It doesn't actually have code for adding test results, however it does say this:

"In order to associate test results and the like, you have to create build project nodes with the fake build."

You should be able to create a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.TestSummary with a summary of your test results.

There's a couple of internal classes that look interesting, specifically Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Controls.TestRunDetails, which could potentially be useful if you don't mind using some reflection.

However what I would recommend, is using the API to look at the nodes in a standard TFS build to see how they are built up.